# slideindown wow from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

i try to reach the same animation like this link http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html, the doge image come from way top to bottom
how to get the animation like that.

heres my code

```
<div class="about-title">
                    <h1 class="text-center title">
                        <?php
                        $about_title = get_field('about_title', 'option');
                        ?>
                        <?php if(strlen($about_title) > 0): ?>
                            <?php echo $about_title; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </h1>
                    <hr class="divider wow animated slideInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                </div>

<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added animate.css? Refere this link for complete working example : http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html

Comment: yap i already include the css. and its work, but i need to the hr to drop from top of window (i mean way far )

Answer (score 0):

Replace "slideInDown" to "fadeInDownBig".... This is the solution for you..